# installing Ipopt for anaconda python

Tags: python, ipopt

Has anyone installed Ipopt on Anaconda python? I downloaded the version 3.6.1. Addditionally, I downloaded the [requested intel Fortran libraries](http://www.gams.com/~svigerske/intel/x86_64/10.1) as described in the readme file.

The install should be straight forward by using `configure` `make` and `make install` with all dependencies linked to it. I hope I will figure that out by myself.

What else do I have to consider if I would like to use Ipopt within anaconda ? In particular I would like to build Pygmo with the Ipopt included.

Or is it sufficient to install pyopt or Casadi ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have installed ipopt on an anaconda environment via the anaconda cloud; ipopt on the anaconda cloud is available on https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ipopt.

To install ipopt on an anaconda environment, you just need to open an anaconda terminal, activate the environment you wish to install ipopt on, then type: "conda install -c conda-forge ipopt", then proceed normally as you would in installing other packages.

Comment: nice to see that ipopt is finally available in anaconda. What about the licences of different solvers for ipopt ?

Answer (score 3):

IPOPT comes with Gekko if you don't want the headaches of compiling the solver on any platform that runs Python (Windows, MacOS, Linux, ARM Linux - Raspberry Pi). Here is a simple example:

```bash
pip install gekko
```

**Solve HS71 with IPOPT**

[image: optimization problem]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO    
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Array(m.Var,4,value=1,lb=1,ub=5)
x1,x2,x3,x4 = x
# change initial values
x2.value = 5; x3.value = 5
m.Equation(x1*x2*x3*x4>=25)
m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2+x4**2==40)
m.Minimize(x1*x4*(x1+x2+x3)+x3)
m.solve()
print('x: ', x)
print('Objective: ',m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
```

Results with IPOPT

```
******************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
 Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
         For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
******************************************************************************

This is Ipopt version 3.12.10, running with linear solver ma57.

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:        9
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:       10

Total number of variables............................:        5
                     variables with only lower bounds:        1
                variables with lower and upper bounds:        4
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:        2
Total number of inequality constraints...............:        0
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        0

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0  1.6109693e+01 1.12e+01 2.50e+00   0.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0
   1  1.6905655e+01 7.44e-01 5.14e-01  -0.9 1.36e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
   2  1.7136202e+01 1.71e-01 4.57e-01  -1.0 9.40e-02    -  8.95e-01 1.00e+00h  1
   3  1.6956645e+01 1.57e-01 7.85e-02  -2.0 1.78e-01    -  9.95e-01 1.00e+00h  1
   4  1.7009269e+01 1.63e-02 1.20e-02  -2.8 3.94e-02    -  9.94e-01 1.00e+00h  1
   5  1.7013888e+01 4.04e-04 1.76e-04  -4.6 6.22e-03    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   6  1.7014017e+01 3.92e-07 6.03e-07 -10.4 1.46e-04    -  9.99e-01 1.00e+00h  1

Number of Iterations....: 6

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:   1.7014017127073458e+01    1.7014017127073458e+01
Dual infeasibility......:   6.0264909533529361e-07    6.0264909533529361e-07
Constraint violation....:   3.9234873865091858e-07    3.9234873865091858e-07
Complementarity.........:   7.2865190881096349e-08    7.2865190881096349e-08
Overall NLP error.......:   6.0264909533529361e-07    6.0264909533529361e-07


Number of objective function evaluations             = 7
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 7
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 7
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 7
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 6
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =      0.003
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      0.000

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
 
 The solution was found.
 
 The final value of the objective function is    17.0140171270735     
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :   9.299999990616925E-003 sec
 Objective      :    17.0140171270735     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
x:  [[1.000000057] [4.74299963] [3.8211500283] [1.3794081795]]
Objective:  17.014017127
```

The default is to use a cloud compute service with more capable linear solvers. A local option is available for IPOPT on Windows but uses the MUMPS linear solver as one of the free distribution options.

Answer (score 0):

I am not particularly familiar with Casadi, but the selection of your optimisation interface will depend pretty much in what are you expecting to do with your problem. For a simple optimisation problem you may use scipy.minimize, for example.

In principle, both (refeering to pyOpt and PyGMO) give you different set of functionalities. For example, PyGMO has other functionalities such as Dr. PyGMO and the possibility of use the Generalised Island Model. In your particular case, you will have to decide on your own what suits you best.

If the task you are doing explicitly requires the use of Ipopt, then the configuration of either PyGMO, pyOpt, or other interface should be a secondary item to whatever you preffer.