# Install Ipopt solver to use with Pyomo in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, pyomo, ipopt

How can I install ipopt solver to use it with pyomo in ubuntu???
I have already download the zip file of [ipopt](http://ampl.com/products/solvers/open-source/)

but I don'n find any specific instructions how to install it and use it with pyomo.

Comment: I found these instructions helpful: https://github.com/casadi/casadi/wiki/InstallationLinux

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73911876/3614578

Answer (score 6):

If you downloaded a binary then you just have to make sure that the ipopt executable is in your PATH environment variable. If you are trying to install from source code you should follow the instructions [here](https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/). Your last option is to use anaconda to install an ipopt binary using the command:

```
conda install -q -y --channel cachemeorg ipopt_bin
```

I think conda installs an old version of ipopt so be aware.

With any of these installations you will know it is installed correctly when you type `ipopt` in a terminal window and get the following output:

```
No stub!
usage: ipopt [options] stub [-AMPL] [<assignment> ...]

Options:
    --  {end of options}
    -=  {show name= possibilities}
    -?  {show usage}
    -e  {suppress echoing of assignments}
    -s  {write .sol file (without -AMPL)}
    -v  {just show version}
```

Comment: Rather than using cachemeorg channel, you may use conda-forge. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48988436/4653485.