# No executable found for solver 'ipopt' in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pyomo, ipopt

I am trying to solve an optimization problem in `pyomo` by using `ipopt` as solver. My OS is `ubuntu`. However I am getting the following error"

```
pyomo.common.errors.ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'ipopt'
```

I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/silgon/0892f410b025f2a82f2b), namely I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc g++ gfortran git cmake liblapack-dev pkg-config --install-recommends
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install coinor-libipopt-dev
```

But I still getting the same error. Any idea of how can I bypass it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.  It appears to be an Ubuntu software installation problem, so it should be asked on the AskUbuntu site

Comment: There exist at least 5 similar questions,  which have the same question, but different characteristics and they are not closed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73911876/3614578

Answer (score 3):

first things first...

After installing, did you log out COMPLETELY or restart your computer to register the new environment variables upon re-login?

In a terminal window you should be able to type:

```
>which ipopt
```

And get a path back to the registered executable (or a symbolic link).  This is the executable that python/pyomo is calling to solve the optimization.  If you get "not found" or such, then it isn't installed properly and you need to go back to the coin-or site and look for instructions.

If it is installed, you should finally verify that it is "callable" from the same command prompt.  It should look similar to this:

```
>ipopt

No stub!
usage: ipopt [options] stub [-AMPL] [<assignment> ...]

Options:
    --  {end of options}
    -=  {show name= possibilities}
    -?  {show usage}
    -bf {read boundsfile f}
    -e  {suppress echoing of assignments}
    -of {write .sol file to file f}
    -s  {write .sol file (without -AMPL)}
    -v  {just show version}
```

If you know where it is installed or you can search and find the executable, navigate to that folder (it is likely inside the version numbered folder) and the `bin` (binaries) folder under the version number.  Then try to run the executable from there with the `ipopt` command.  If that works, you know the install location and you could:

- unpdate your environment variables to include that.  (I'm not versed on Unbuntu) but this can be screwed up and cause big problems if you don't know what you are doing.
- copy that path and simply provide that path in `pyomo` when you ask the solver factory for the solver and provide the path reference.  On my machine that would be this location where Homebrew installs a symbolic link:

---

```
solver = SolverFactory('ipopt', executable='/usr/local/bin/ipopt')
```

If none of this gets you anywhere, you might want to use Homebrew to install it (instead of `apt-get`) ... Instructions are on the coin-or site I believe and I think that is all compatible with Ubuntu.

Comment: It only worked for me when I added `executable='/usr/local/bin/ipopt'` even though `ipopt` was in my PATH